# Remote Event receiver ItemAdded and ItemUpdated issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, remote-event-receiver

I have added itemUpdated functionality to my receiver but i notice that it overide my itemAdded function. whenever i add a new item, my RER is not triggered. But on editing RER is triggered.

```
EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
                receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
                receiver.EventType=EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated;


                //Get WCF URL where this message was handled
                OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
                Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
                receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();

                receiver.ReceiverName = RECEIVER_NAME;
                receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;

                //Add the new event receiver to a list in the host web
                jobsList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why but only this work for me compare to the other answers.

```
 EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
            receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;



            //Get WCF URL where this message was handled
            OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
            Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
            receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();

            receiver.ReceiverName = RECEIVER_NAME;
            receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;

            //Add the new event receiver to a list in the host web
            jobsList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Added ItemAdded receiver at " + receiver.ReceiverUrl);


            //add a second event receiver for item updated
            EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiverupdate = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
            receiverupdate.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated;


            //Get WCF URL where this message was handled
            OperationContext opupdate = OperationContext.Current;
            Message msgupdate = opupdate.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
            receiverupdate.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();

            receiverupdate.ReceiverName = "Item Updated";
            receiverupdate.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;

            //Add the new event receiver to a list in the host web
            jobsList.EventReceivers.Add(receiverupdate);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Added ItemAdded receiver at " + receiver.ReceiverUrl);
```

Comment: Item updated event worked for you? You need to give your Event Receiver name correctly, against  "receiverupdate.ReceiverName".

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245302.aspx

Comment: Your answer is the same as what we have advised you In the above answers *"you should add each EventType to list independently"* !! also, you should clarify why the above answers are not working for you?

Comment: @M.Qassas i have no idea why it wasnt working, the rer wasnt working at all.

Answer (score 5):

**It's** a normal behavior, where

You have set `EventType` to `ItemAdded`

```
receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
```

Then in the next line, the `EventType` is set (overwrite) to `ItemUpdated` again!

```
receiver.EventType=EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated;
```

So the On `ItemUpdated` event only will work!

---

**To overcome this issue,** you should add each `EventType` to list **independently** as the following

```
public static void ApplyEventReceiver(ClientContext context, List list)
{
// First Event ItemAdded
EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation eventReceiver = Helpers.BuildGenericEventRecieverWithoutEventType();
eventReceiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
if (!DoesEventReceiverDefintionExistBasedOnCreationInfo(eventReceiver, list))
{
list.EventReceivers.Add(eventReceiver);
}

// Second Event ItemUpdated
eventReceiver = BuildGenericEventRecieverWithoutEventType();
eventReceiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated;
if (!DoesEventReceiverDefintionExistBasedOnCreationInfo(eventReceiver, list))
{
list.EventReceivers.Add(eventReceiver);
}

context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Check also [Adding Remote Event Receivers To An Existing List In Office 365](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/adding-remote-event-receivers-to-an-exisiting-list-in-office-365/)

Answer (score 5):

Attch both `ItemAdded` & `ItemUpdated` seperately.

```
var lstJob = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LISTNAME");
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;

EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation addEventReceiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
{
    EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded, /* ITEM ADDED*/
    ReceiverName = "RECEIVER_NAME",
    ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString()
};

lstJob.EventReceivers.Add(addEventReceiver);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation updateEventReceiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
{
    EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated, /* ITEM UPDATE*/
    ReceiverName = "RECEIVER_NAME",
    ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString()
};

lstJob.EventReceivers.Add(updateEventReceiver);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: doesnt work at all i dont know why

Comment: Is there any error showing ?

Comment: no error just nothing is triggered

Comment: Refer these links, might solve the issue. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636058/Adventures-with-SharePoint-Remote-Event-Recei , https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/